# Installing the VC Redistributable (2015|2017|2019) for both x86 and x64 using Inno Setup

Tags: installer, pascal-script

I don't have a virtual computer so I am not able to beta test this installation. Therefore I am kindly asking if I have gone about this correctly. It compiles OK.

## Step 1

I declared these variables:

```
var
  vcRedist64BitPath: string;
  vcRedist32BitPath: string;
  bVcRedist64BitNeeded : boolean;
  bVcRedist32BitNeeded : boolean;

const
  // See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
  vcRedist64BitURL = 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe';
  vcRedist32BitURL = 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x86.exe';
```

## Step 2

I implemented these functions to test if the x86 and x64 redistributables are already installed:

```
// See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51614652/2287576
function IsVCRedist64BitNeeded(): boolean;
var
  strVersion: string;
begin
  if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64', 'Version', strVersion)) then
  begin
    // Is the installed version at least 14.14 ? 
    Log('VC Redist x64 Version : found ' + strVersion);
    Result := (CompareStr(strVersion, 'v14.14.26429.03') < 0);
  end
  else
  begin
    // Not even an old version installed
    Log('VC Redist x64 is not already installed');
    Result := True;
  end;
end;

function IsVCRedist32BitNeeded(): boolean;
var
  strVersion: string;
begin
  if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86', 'Version', strVersion)) then
  begin
    // Is the installed version at least 14.14 ? 
    Log('VC Redist x86 Version : found ' + strVersion);
    Result := (CompareStr(strVersion, 'v14.14.26429.03') < 0);
  end
  else
  begin
    if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
      'SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x86', 'Version', strVersion)) then
    begin
      // Is the installed version at least 14.14 ? 
      Log('VC Redist x86 Version : found ' + strVersion);
      Result := (CompareStr(strVersion, 'v14.14.26429.03') < 0);
    end
    else
    begin
      // Not even an old version installed
      Log('VC Redist x86 is not already installed');
      Result := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

As I understand it, from the SO answer in the comment, 14.14 is the 2015 redistributable package and 2015 through 2019 use the same binaries. So I assume it is acceptable to look for this version in the registry.

## Step 3

I updated `PrepareToInstall`:

```
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
begin
  result := '';

  bVcRedist64BitNeeded := false;
  if(IsWin64()) then
  begin
    bVcRedist64BitNeeded := IsVCRedist64BitNeeded();
  end;
  bVcRedist32BitNeeded := IsVCRedist32BitNeeded();
end;
```

## Step 4

Since I am using DWinsHs for downloading remote files I added the following two entries to the `BeforeDownload` callback:

```
function BeforeDownload(): boolean;
begin
  if(bVcRedist64BitNeeded) then
  begin
    // We need to download the 64 Bit VC Redistributable from the Microsoft Website
    vcRedist64BitPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\vc_redist.x64.exe');
    DwinsHs_AppendRemoteFile( vcRedist64BitPath, 
                  vcRedist64BitURL, 'My_Setup', rmGet, FILESIZE_QUERY_SERVER );
  end;

  if(bVcRedist32BitNeeded) then
  begin
    // We need to download the 32 Bit VC Redistributable from the Microsoft Website
    vcRedist32BitPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\vc_redist.x86.exe');
    DwinsHs_AppendRemoteFile( vcRedist32BitPath, 
                  vcRedist32BitURL, 'My_Setup', rmGet, FILESIZE_QUERY_SERVER );
  end;

  result := true;
end;
```

## Step 5

Since I am using DWinsHs for downloading remote files I added the following two entries to the `AfterDownload` callback:

```
procedure AfterDownload(State: integer);
var
  ResultCode: integer;
begin
  if (State = READ_OK) then
  begin
    if(bVcRedist64BitNeeded) then
    begin
      if Exec(ExpandConstant(vcRedist64BitPath), '/install /passive /norestart', '',
          SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then begin
        // handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code
        if not (ResultCode = 0) then begin
          MsgBox(ExpandConstant('The installation of Visual Studio x64 Redistributable failed. The Meeting Schedule Assistant installation will be aborted.'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
          Abort();
        end;
      end
      else begin
        // The execution failed for some reason
        MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);
        Abort();
      end;
    end;

    if(bVcRedist32BitNeeded) then
    begin
      if Exec(ExpandConstant(vcRedist32BitPath), '/install /passive /norestart', '',
          SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then begin
        // handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code
        if not (ResultCode = 0) then begin
          MsgBox(ExpandConstant('The installation of Visual Studio x86 Redistributable failed. The Meeting Schedule Assistant installation will be aborted.'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
          Abort();
        end;
      end
      else begin
        // The execution failed for some reason
        MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbInformation, MB_OK);
        Abort();
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The installer parameters and registry keys I have obtained are from resources I have found on the internet.

My installer caters for both x86 and x64 file .exe files which is why I am detecting if both redistributables are installed.

Have I in principle done this correctly? Again, I do not have a virtual environment to test with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code,

1. Please move lines in `PrepareToInstall` method to `BeforeDownload` method:

```
  bVcRedist64BitNeeded := false;
  if(IsWin64()) then
  begin
    bVcRedist64BitNeeded := IsVCRedist64BitNeeded();
  end;
  bVcRedist32BitNeeded := IsVCRedist32BitNeeded();
```

Because the `BeforeDownload` is called earlier than `PrepareToInstall` method.

2. Then add method:

```
    procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
    begin
      DwinsHs_CurPageChanged(CurPageID, @BeforeDownload, @AfterDownload);
    end;
```

Also you can use the `DwinsHs_Check` to add the download files:

```
[files]
Source: "{tmp}\a.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}\vc_redist.x32.exe"; Flags: external; Check: IsVCRedist32BitNeeded() and DwinsHs_Check(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\a.exe'), 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x86.exe', 'My_Setup', 'Get', 0, 0 );
Source: "{tmp}\b.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}\vc_redist.x64.exe"; Flags: external; Check: IsWin64() and IsVCRedist64BitNeeded() and DwinsHs_Check(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\b.exe'), 'https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe', 'My_Setup', 'Get', 0, 0 );
```

then remove the `BeforeDownload` method.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be better to cache the Is...Needed values first and then use the cached values? Otherwise we would have to run the same checks again in AfterDownload.